# Anyone some have "ERC20 Deposit Contract" sample code?

Tags: solidity

I'm looking for an example contract that works like this:

> There is a person A, a person B, an ERC20 token named abc, and a
>   smart contract C,
>
> Person A sends `20abc` to contract C, and 30 minutes
>   later, the contract C sends 20abc to person B.

It doesn't need to be reusable, i.e., it doesn't need to support multiple deposits.

Comment: Did you use some automatic translate service (like Google Translate or similar)? If yes, then it did a pretty bad job. This question (if it can even be called "question") is practically unreadable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contract `C` is not able to send funds or perform any actions without an outside transaction triggering the action. Thus the requirement for the contract to automatically send the ERC20 token 30 min later seems not possible.

However you can:

- Build a contract where A can deposit funds, and B could trigger a withdrawal after 30 min have passed.
- Build a contract where A can deposit funds to contract C, and it will right away transfer the funds to user B.